# Как создать большой развернутый календарь с плагином air-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, плагин, календарь

Нужно создать такой большой календарь где человек выбирает даты, переходит на следующий год , там выбирает даты и т.д.
Я пытаюсь решить следующим образом:

```
// календарь где отображается только год с переключателем
$('#big-calendar__year').datepicker({ 
    inline: true,
    view: "months",
    showOtherYears: false,
    navTitles: {
        days: 'MM <i>yyyy</i>',
        months: 'yyyy',
        years: 'yyyy'
    },
    onChangeYear: function() { // событие при изменении года.
        // сюда пытаюсь написать код который меняет год в других
        // календарях без изменения месяца
    }
});
// календарь где отображается месяц
let thisDate = new Date(); // текщая дата
let thisYear = thisDate.getUTCFullYear(); // текущий год
let Jan = new Date(thisYear, 0, 1); // всегда январь любого года
$('#big-calendar__months').datepicker({
    firstDay: 0,
    weekends: [0],
    inline: true,
    showOtherMonths: false,
    multipleDates: true,
    view: "days",
    startDate: Jan,
    navTitles: {
        days: 'MM',
        months: 'yyyy',
        years: 'yyyy'
    }
});
```

Важно чтобы датапикер просто переключал календарь, а не перерисовывал

[image: Большой развернутый календарь]

Comment: Создавайте, в чем проблема? Это слишком общий вопрос, судя по которому вы сами даже не пытались.

Comment: Пытался, но не получилось из-за незнания js. Если не трудно подскажите правильный ответ.

Comment: Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, и добавьте код в него, а не в комментарий

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю air-datepicker, невозможно просто так это сделать.
Придется делать самому) flex-контейнер с девятью датапикерами, динамически раздать им месяца года - задача в принципе на полчаса-час

Comment: Спасибо. Да, так и сделал. Но хотелось бы узнать "true" способ. Или хотя бы такой вариант, где при клике на кнопку у всех датапикеров менялся только год.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение c помощью плагина "bootstrap-year-calendar"